# Is there a way for Selenium to verify if the number of items fits a criteria?

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

Is there a way for selenium to create something along these lines:

```
verifyXpathCount     //div[@class='display']/table/tbody/tr      <=10
```

i.e. I want to verify that table contains less or equal 10 `<tr>` items inside body of specified table.
Or is this beyond the scope of Selenium IDE (version 1.5)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
storeXpathCount  |   [your xpath]                     |   myCount
verifyEval       |   ${myCount} <= 10 ? true : false  |   true
```

Basically you are storing the number of elements found by the xpath expression to `myCount` and then you can check that an arbitrary expression using that number evaluates to true (in this case we are checking that the number is less than 10).

Comment: Seems to be the thing I was looking for. Thougha subquestion what kind of language is the `${myCount} <= 10 ? true : false`? Looks like Java or JSP to me. Is there a definition of it on site that I missed?

Comment: it is javascript. The command verifyEval means it will verify that the result of the javascript command equals the expected value. So the line is a ternay operator: [condition] ? [result if true] : [result if false]